# update createdAt & updatedAt fields automatically in symfony3 (doctrine)

Tags: doctrine-orm, entity, symfony

I have an entity (*Server*) that should have two extra fields: **createdAt** and **updatedAt** (*like cakephp*). I tried this on `Server` entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\PrePersist
 * @ORM\PreUpdate
 */
public function updateTimestamp()
    {
        $this->setModifiedAt(new \DateTime());
        if($this->getCreatedAt() == null){
            $this->setCreatedAt(new \DateTime());
        }
    }
```

but nothing happened during update process. Then I searched about it and there was this `EventListener` solution.

I couldn't fix it by that too.

is there any solution for this problem, please provide a step by step solution.

thank  you a lot and sorry for bad English! ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check you have the `HasLifecycleCallbacks` annotation on your entity, as example:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
class Server
```

Hope this help