# Symfony - Dynamically edit property

Tags: symfony

Imagine I have a "Product" Class that has 3 properties (creationTimestamp, name and price).

I do not want the user to change the name once the object has been created. No problem for that: I added an Event Subscriber to the FormType.

In addition, I do never show the creationTimestamp in my create and edit forms. I want this field to be populated "in the background" only when I create the object. It should not change when I edit my object. Question: should I put the logic in the Controller or somewhere else (ie. a Lifecycle Callback). What is the best practice ? A syntax example would be really appreciated. Thank you in advance

Comment: are you working with Doctrine entities?

Comment: Yes I am using Doctrine entities

Comment: check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36028891/update-createdat-updatedat-fields-automatically-in-symfony3-doctrine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it in the constructor.

```
class Product
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $nowTimestamp = 123456789; //Here your timestamp value
        $this->setCreationTimestamp($nowTimestamp); //Assuming that you have defined setter function
    }
}
```

Comment: when dealing with Doctrine entities you shouldn't rely on the constructor as it's not called by Doctrine. That's why I suggested Lifecycle Callbacks for PrePersist (and PreUpdate) in my comment.

Comment: Yes but how can I determine if it a new object or not within a lifecycle callback ?

Comment: just use PrePersist only